# Time complexity for constant length loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am having a hard time deciding how to state the worst-case runtime complexity of a function within a class.

This class stores two kinds of objects, say N and M, possibly millions of them.

One of the operations just searches for the best place to store an item:

```
void foo(item) {
    for (int i=0;i<K;i++) {
        for (int j=i;j<K;j++) {
            if(store(i,j,item)) // store is O(1)
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Here K, is a problem defined constant (say 10). In the worst case the item might not be stored and the loops will be exhausted.

I can't decide if it's more correct to say foo has O(1) complexity, as K is a given constant that doesn't depend on N and M; or it's better to say complexity is O(k<sup>2</sup>). Maybe even amortized O(1) ?

Comment: If `k` is a constant, this is definetly in the bounds of `O(1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> K is a given constant that doesn't depend on N and M

Note that the first and last part of the sentence are not self-contradicting.

If `k` doesn't depend on `M,N` - it does not mean it does not independently grows. If it does grow (does not matter in what rate), of is a parameter of your function - the complexity depends on it and is indeed `O(k^2)`.

If `k` is constant and never changes, this is indeed O(1), because `k^2 < C` for some **constant** `C=k^2+1`.

Common examples of usage of constant values in iterations are:

- Going over a finite size alphabet when doing strings algorithms ([trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for example)
- Going over bits of fixed integers.

These are regarded as `O(1)`, even though they are implemented with a loop, what matters is - the time
   processing the loop is bounded by a finite size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @amit. The alphabet example is eye opener. It's just that I couldn't find a single reference to this case in forums or literature. All I found was the simpler "looping is O(N^k)" .

Comment: @bts Do not be confused with constant in exponent. `O(n^k)` is different than `O(n^(k+1))` and cannot be ignored. I think the most common case you see when analyzing programs, is assuming integers are bounded to a constant size (usually 2^31), and thus arithmetic operations on integers are considered `O(1)`. (This is not the case if using unbounded integers libraries).

Answer (score 3):

It is more informative and harmless to say that the complexity is O(K²). Then, knowing that K is bounded, you would implicitly conclude that this is O(1).

In practice, the hidden constant being 5 or 5000000 makes a difference.

Comment: I would even consider it a little dishonest to hide a constant known to be large behind the O(1) notation.